# Inconsistent values from NTP client

Tags: nodemcu, time

Hardware- ESP8266 Based NodeMCU

I am using NTP Client for time in my alarm project.

I am facing an issue where NTP client is not returning proper values, in the sense that it works properly for the first few hours- returning the time every second, however after some time the values go haywire.

First few hours:-

```
21:00:45
21:00:46
21:00:47
21:00:48
```

After sometime:-

```
06:00:02
06:00:45
06:00:49
```

What could be the cause of this and how do prevent it?

Comment: don't use NTP library on esp. esp has 'built-in' ntp functions. see the esp8266/NTP-TZ-DST.ino in IDE examples menu

Comment: `returning the time every second` ... maybe the NTP server starts to ignore your request

Comment: @jsotala I'm only using ```timeClient.getFormattedTime``` and ```timeClient.update()``` , in my loop, I have found out that ```timeClient.update()``` does not return anything until the update interval is over, which in my case is about 10 mins